# Pulling HTML value through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these data-attributes

```
<li data-audio="" data-pic="images/one.png" data-word="one" data-hint="What?"></li>
```

I pull them through using this function

```
$(wordsData).each(function () {
    var elm = $(this);
    listOfWords.push({
        "name": elm.data("word"),
        "pic": elm.data("pic"),
        "hint": elm.data("hint"),
        "audio": elm.data("audio")
    });
});
```

My problem is that when I pull the picture through I would like to display the hint in the same div. But for some reason when I check in the console it says value="", when it should say "What?"

```
<div class="hint-img-wrapper">
<img src="" value="" id="hintPic" class="pic-hint" alt="Hint" />
```

I display it it like this

```
 $("#hintPic").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].pic).attr('value', listOfWords[rndWord].hint);
        $(hintPic).show();
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `value` is not a valid attribute on an `<img>` tag. Use an HTML5 `data-` attribute like your other code. What are you trying to accomplish with the `value` attribute there anyway?

Comment: Code seems correct, which version of jQuery did you use?

Comment: So I have changed value for title, will this work? If so what do I cange in the markup?

Comment: If you inspect value attribute from console and get nothing, it *must* be a problem with code and not markup or anything else, try to step-by-step debug this code, to see if `rndWord` is a correct number value that could retrieve a valid data object from `listOfWords`?

Comment: the only one not working is the data-hint, the others work fine @otakustay

Comment: So you checked from console that `$('#hintPic).attr('value')` is an empty string? I put an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/otakustay/9WuQP/ is there any different between my code and yours that causes your problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19233/discussion-between-milo-j-and-otakustay)

Comment: @otakustay: Did you wanna post a question?

Comment: @Milo-J It's better you post the answer yourself since I don't know what exactly the problem is and how you finally solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to set instead of `.attr('value', listOfWords[rndWord].hint);` is `.attr('title', listOfWords[rndWord].hint);`

The title property is what's normally displayed if you hover over an image. If no title is specified it will use the alt property.

Comment: what would I change in the Html @Sargo Darya

Comment: You don't need to change anything in the HTML. The last snippet of code is just a bit wrong. You're setting value (which is not even a valid property for the img tag) instead of the title property.

Comment: well it still doesn't work. Where else would it say title? @Sargo Darya

Comment: what would <div class="hint-img-wrapper">
<img src="" value="" id="hintPic" class="pic-hint" alt="Hint" /> change to

Comment: If you want to display the text directly you should change the markup to `<div class="hint-img-wrapper"> <img src="" value="" id="hintPic" class="pic-hint" alt="Hint" /><span class="hintText"></span></div>` and in the javascript code you put `$('.hint-img-wrapper').find('.hindText').text(listOfWords[rndWord].hint)'`